# where can i find SharedCache with fluent nhibernate getting started guid

Tags: caching, fluent-nhibernate

where can i find SharedCache with fluent nhibernate getting started guid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is very little documentation I've found for getting SharedCache working with NHibernate, let alone doing it fluently.  However, it's not a hard process:

1. You need to tell NHibernate you're using SharedCache as a cache provider.  [Another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020730/nhibernate-l2-cache-configuration-in-fluent-nhibernate/2029224#2029224) gives a sample implementation for Fluent NHibernate.  The key bit is the `Cache` function, except here you will want to use `NHibernate.Caches.SharedCache.SharedCacheProvider` instead of `NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider`.

   As an aside, to configure it non fluently you use something like this in your configuration:

   ```
   <add key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="NHibernate.Caches.SharedCache.SharedCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SharedCache" />
   ```

   Or, if you're configuring via Spring.NET with the rest of your NHibernate configuration entries:

   ```
   <entry key="cache.provider_class" value="NHibernate.Caches.SharedCache.SharedCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SharedCache" />
   ```
2. You will then need to add web.config / app.config entries for the cache as you would when using SharedCache without NHibernate, for example:

   ```
   <configSections>
       <section name="indexusNetSharedCache" type="MergeSystem.Indexus.WinServiceCommon.Configuration.Client.IndexusProviderSection, MergeSystem.Indexus.WinServiceCommon" />
   </configSections>

   <indexusNetSharedCache defaultProvider="IndexusSharedCacheProvider">
       <servers>
           <add key="myServer1" ipaddress="127.0.0.1" port="48888"/>
       </servers>
       <providers>
           <add name="IndexusSharedCacheProvider" type="MergeSystem.Indexus.WinServiceCommon.Provider.Cache.IndexusSharedCacheProvider, MergeSystem.Indexus.WinServiceCommon" />
       </providers>
   </indexusNetSharedCache>
   ```

You can find plenty more information about configuring a SharedCache client [on their website](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/shared_cache_configuration_client.aspx), although be sure to configure each server too.

Hope this helps - I haven't been able to fully test this, so I may've made a mistake somewhere.