# NHibernate L2 Cache configuration in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: configuration, caching, fluent-nhibernate, velocity

Is ti possible to configure the L2 cache provider in code via FHN?

Adding a line to the following config is what I'm after:

```
 return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Temp")).ShowSql())
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<IMap>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(c => { })
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Cheers

AWC

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is possible from FNH, in the example below see the 'Cache' property:

```
return Fluently.Configure(fileConfiguration)
  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
    .MsSql2005
      .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Temp"))
      .ShowSql()
      .Cache(c => c.ProviderClass(typeof(NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName)
          .UseQueryCache()))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<IMap>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => {
        c.EventListeners.PostLoadEventListeners = new IPostLoadEventListener[] {new TestPostLoadListener()};
      })
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Cheers

AWC

---

Note, for Fluent NHibernate >= 3.4.0.0 it appears the configuration is slightly different.  Use the nuget package for SysCache from http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Caches.SysCache

```
return Fluently.Configure(fileConfiguration)
  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
    .MsSql2005
      .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Temp"))
      .ShowSql())
    .Cache(c => c.ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>().UseQueryCache())
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<IMap>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => {
        c.EventListeners.PostLoadEventListeners = new IPostLoadEventListener[] {new TestPostLoadListener()};
      })
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: ProviderClass method accepts type parameter and usage can be rewritten as `c.ProviderClass<HashTableCacheProvider>()`. :)

Comment: Just a note you probably already know: do not use the HashTable Cacheprovider for production code.

Comment: Why not? What are the other options available?