# Using MemCached with Fluent Nhibernate in S#arp Architercture

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, memcached, s#arp-architecture

I'm using S#arp architecture to develop my web site. I've decided on using memcached as my caching system. I've successfuly managed to incorporate the memcached into my web site but I'm finding some problems while trying to do so with my FNH objects. 
I've seen some code explaining how to use this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020730/nhibernate-l2-cache-configuration-in-fluent-nhibernate), but I can't figure out where this code should be placed. Please Help me.

Thanks,

Izhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your looking to do is not currently possible with out of the box S# as it makes using of NHibernateInitializer that does not take this into account. In the 3.0 version, we will be getting rid of this class in favor of initializing NH differently that will allow others to modify as they need.

Sorry I could not be of more help with this.